# How to count how many words are in a text string inputted by the user in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, counter

I was wondering if anybody could help; I'm quite new to python.

I'm currently creating a tool which analyses the text inputted by a user and shows which feedback to which list that phrase belongs to.

So far the programme is on an infinite loop and counts how many expressions have been entered all together and then how many times something has occurred in a certain list.

```
if text in access:
    accessno +=1
    counter +=1
    print ('This could be classed as speech act 1: Access')
    print ("number of access hits ", accessno)
    print ("number of total hits ", counter)
```

So my question is this: how does one also get the programme to count how many words are in a sentence inputted by the user?

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: If you feel any of the answers below have provided you with a solution, please mark it as accepted.

Comment: It wont allow me due to being new on here! but thank you, you have helped a lot! :)

Comment: You can mark the answers on your own question as accepted, on the top left of the answer near the numbers. Your edit after the question has been solved changes your question too much, I will revert it to its original state, comments should be made as comments, not in your question, if you MUST include it in your question, add it on the bottom as an edit without changing the original meaning.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it in the following simple way.

```
s = input()
# input() is a function that gets input from the user
len(s.split())
# len() checks the length of a list, s.split() splits the users input into a word list.
```

Links:

[input()](http://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input)
[len()](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#len)
[split()](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split)

---

Example:

```
>>> s = input()
"hello world"
>>> s
'hello world'
>>> s.split()
['hello', 'world']
>>> len(s.split())
2
```

---

Bonus: Do it all in one line!

```
print('You wrote {} words!'.format(len(input("Enter some text, I will tell you how many words you wrote!: ").split())))
```

Comment: Looks like the OP is using Python 3 (`print` is a function in the given code, not a statement), so you would use `input()` instead.

Comment: Ah that simple! where ive got the user entering the code it currently is print ('Hello, Welcome to the chat log assistant')
text = input('Please enter your text:') Yes its Python 3

Comment: @Volatility You can never know for sure unless OP confirms it, it's still valid Python 2 code, however OP does most likely use Python 3

Comment: `input()` is better as `raw_input()`: it shows that a string is expected (`input()` interprets strings). Also, `input("")` is more simply and naturally written as `input()`, since there is no input prompt (and is better as `raw_input()`).

Comment: @EOL You are right, it was originally raw_input, but I switched it to input because 3.0. They are different in 2 and 3. So although you make a valid point, in 3 it is simply not so.

Comment: @InbarRose: My bad, you're right, I had missed the Python 3 tag. +1.

Answer (score -1):

```
name = input ()
print len(name)
```

Comment: This will give the length of the entire string, not the number of words.

Comment: Omg, god I need to go to bed.

Comment: This works a treat: 
    print ('Hello, Welcome to the chat log assistant')
    text = input('Please enter your text:')                                                            len(text.split())                                                      print ("You have entered " + text )
if text in access:
print ("total number of words" ,len(text.split()))

Cheers guys!